# Why FFMPEG cancel my command about cut and fusion

Tags: ffmpeg

Somebody can help me for this error please :

"D:\Enregistrements>"D:\ffmpeg-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner
-i "D:\Enregistrements\Test.mp4"
-vf "select='between(t,0.00,39.37)+between(t,66.32,159.05)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB"
-af "select='between(t,0.00,39.37)+between(t,66.32,159.05)',asetpts=N/SAMPLE_RATE/TB"
"D:\Enregistrements\Test_Coupe0 (1).mp4"
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\Enregistrements\Test.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf59.4.101
Duration: 00:05:00.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2215 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 (SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9), 2099 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
(Parsed_select_0 @ 0000017d2feac700) Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_select_0' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_asetpts_1' filter input pad 0 (audio)
(AVFilterGraph @ 0000017d2feac680) Cannot create the link select:0 -> asetpts:0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!*

Thank you

Comment: It should be `aselect` in the `-af` filterchain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's perfect.